# REST design: what verb and resource name to use for a filtering service

Tags: http, rest, webserver, restful-architecture

I am developing a cleanup/filtering service that has a method that receives a list of objects serialized in xml, and apply some filtering rules to return a subset of those objects.

1. In a REST-ful service, what verb shall I use for such a method? I thought that GET is a natural choice, but I have to put the serialized XML in the body of the request which works but feels incorrect. The other verbs don't seem to fit semantically.
2. What is a good way to define that Service interface? Naming the resource /Cleanup or /Filter seems weird mainly because in the examples I see online, it is always a name rather than a verb being used for resource name.
3. Am I right to feel that REST services are better suited for CRUD operations and you start bending the rules in situations like this service? If yes, am I then making a wrong architectural choice.
4. I've pushed to develop this service in REST-ful style (as opposed to SOAP) for simplicity, but such awkward cases happen a lot and make me feel like I am missing something. Either choosing REST where it shouldn't be used or may be over-thinking some stuff that doesn't really matter? In that case, what really matters?

Comment: Can you provide some examples or at least some strawman urls so we understand better what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: is my description in the question not enough: "I am developing a cleanup/filtering service that has a method that receives a list of objects serialized in xml, and apply some filtering rules to return a subset of those objects."

Comment: No - are your methods filtering and returning data (implies a get) or is it filtering and cleaning up and mutating resources on the server (may imply a delete or POST verb depending).

Comment: What would help is an example of the data being passed (regardless of the REST etc...), what work/modifications are done server side and what is expected to be returned to the client - actual data flow example.

Comment: it is not affecting any resources on the server, it is just performing a cleanup on the list of objects passed to it, mainly getting rid of duplicates for now, could do more in the future but it will never mutate resources on the server.

Comment: Does't cleanup imply it's mutating resources?  That's where I got confused - cleanup implies some resources getting deleted.  That shouldn't handle with a GET.  Is it a combination of get and then DELETE calls?  Maybe - not sure because it's not clear.

Comment: I see why you're confused (may be that's part of what I am getting wrong). It receives a set of objects and returns a subset of them deleting the duplicates. The thing is that it is not changing anything server-side, it's just acting on what is passed to it, it's like a helper function that will just perform its functionality on its arguments without affecting any outside server-side resources (no database update, delete for example).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

REST is about using HTTP the way it was designed.  To be RESTful consider (title was REST design :):

- URLs should be permalinks to a resource (caching benefits, storing/sharing endpoints etc...)
- Because they are permalinks to a resource, having verbs in the URL is a hint that you're on the wrong path (filter is a verb).
- A collection of resources can be an endpoint /foos.
- If you want to filter the collection of resources, consider querystring params like ?filter= or something like ?ids=1,2,3,4,5.
- A GET should not change resources.  Note that 'cleanup' implies something getting deleted so be cautious of changes to resources when you do a GET.  REST says a GET shouldn't alter resources.  Imagine a caching server taking you're cleanup request as a GET and returning OK because t's cached.  Caching servers know not to cache a POST, DELETE etc... (that's the way HTTP was designed).
- Don't rule out multiple calls - for example, you may do a get to filter and get a set of resources to clean up and then could be followed by many or one DELETE verb calls to do the cleanup.
- Sometimes there's a temporal resource like a transaction or a 'job' that could do work like a cleanup.  Don't rule out a POST to the resource with the body containing items to cleanup up and it returns a job id.  You can then query the jobid for the cleanup progress or status.

It's hard to give exact guidance because the question isn't clear but hopefully the RESTful principlies guidance and thoughts above set you on the right track.  If you clarify the exact calls, I'll try and recommend APIs.

So, let's say you wanted to cleanup duplicate foos.

[GET] /foos/duplicates (or /foos?filter=duplicates)

returns a body with identifies to of foos that are duplicates.  Let's say that returns 1,2,5 (could be names).

Then you could issue:

[DELETE] /foos with the body being an array containing 1,2,5 (or names if unique).  the delete call is passive so even if the GET call is cached according to REST principles it's fine.

It's also possible and valid to not go the REST route such as POX or JOSN RPC over http but just realize at that point that it's not REST.  And that's fine but you're not getting the benefits of REST described in fielding's thesis.

http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm

Also, read this:

http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2011-07-03-nobody-understands-rest-or-http

EDIT:

After reading the comment where you clarified you're sending the server a set of objects (not persisted server side) and it returns the subset with the dupes filtered out (like a server side helper function), some options are:

1. Do this client/browser side if possible - why take the network roundtrip to filter out dupes out of  collection?
2. If for some reason only the server has specific knowledge/data to determine that two items are functional equivalent (even though data not exactly the same), then consider POSTing the data set to the server with the response body containing the unique/filtered set.  Even though the server isn't persisting the set, it would fall into a 'temporal' object or set and the server is modifying it.  It's not conceptually a GET of server resources and caching offers no benefits in that scenario.

Comment: thanks bryan, bare with me a little more, am almost there :) your Foos example is good, the problem is Foos - in my case - don't exist by themselves, they are just whatever is passed in the body of the request (that's why I said it's like a helper method,  acting on its arguments and has no other side effects, even arguments are passed by value). May be I am not getting "Resources" correctly, would you consider the Foos passed in the request body to be resources? they are not persisted anywhere and a call to GET /Foos won't return anything, they are just what is being passed to the function.

Comment: let's say my example was a method to Sort foos, you pass some foos in the request body, they are sorted according to some rules and passed back. But you can't do a GET /Foos because these don't exist except in the context of the request body. How would you design the API to perform this sort?

Comment: ok just saw the edit ... it's doing the server-trip because some of the rules for deduping involves checking other external resources not available client-side so I guess your #2 answers my question. Just to confirm, POSTing when the data is not persisted is not a violation of REST principles?

Comment: It's an interpretation but at that point it's a temporal object.  There's no difference REST wise whether it stores it in memory to perform the filter or persists it in a file/DB, filters it, then returns it.  The classic example of a temporal object is a job or a transaction - it's short lived.  You're filter request is essentially a temporal job you're deferring to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Last question first: What really matters is getting the job done in a way that is

- Correct
- As easy to use as practical
- Easily maintained by future programmers (likely to include yourself)

REST is a natural fit for operations on resources where each URL matches some object that can be manipulated.  It is a less natural fit for other uses, but **these are more guidelines than actual rules**.  Others have pointed out the original [dissertation on REST](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm), but it is worth remembering that few implementations are pure.

If you have several URLs that perform these transformative kinds of functions, consider putting them in their own special URL space, like `/api/filter` and `/api/transliterate`, etc..  That will help users and maintainers alike know that certain URLs aren't REST, but are more like remote procedure calls.  Posting data to these URLs results in you getting some kind of data back.

If you get stuck on specific names you should make a list of candidates, have a few beers, then choose one from the list.  That's what I do when I get stuck on minutia.

SOAP is a neat protocol and has its uses, but it tends to be very heavy.  Good documentation and consistency are probably more important to your budding API than using any specific technology.

Comment: The REST dissertation goes beyond the bullet points above.  (maybe CORRECT is a catch all).  But one key point of REST is caching and permalinks.  One sign that you're breaking the concept of REST, is if your URLs have verbs like 'filter' in it.  URLs should reference permalink references and if you start compromising that you end up with just POX.

Comment: Here's the dissertation: http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm

Comment: +1 for your naming process... so what about which verb to use?

Comment: @bryanmac so in that case, is REST a wrong choice to start with or is there a way to name my resources to be more consistent with REST style?

Comment: transform and filter are both verbs in the URL - it's RPC masquerading as REST.

Comment: I edited the post some, to incorporate the very good suggestions of others.  As for naming, a URL of `/api/filter` sounds promising.  I'm partial to the word `transmogrify` and its derivatives, but it doesn't sound as if your function rises to level of functionality.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using REST where it is appropriate and useful, and having an API namespace too as long as it is separate.  But reading chapter 5 of Fielding's dissertation might clear things up for you.  For a thesis, it is pretty clear.

Comment: BTW, I'm partial to JSON-RPC when I want to implement remote procedure calls.  There's more than one way to skin that cat.